# Rails - refreshing page with new table entries

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The goal I am trying to achieve is to let the user click on a button which will refresh to page filter that search. My page is dedicated to music artists and would like that once the user selects "Pop", that the page refreshes showing only "pop" artists.

Here is the html + ruby that I am using to display the artists:

```
<% #prints the artists that match the search, prints all for empty search %>
      <% @artists.each_slice(3) do |artists| %>
            <div class="row">
              <% artists.each do |artist| %>
                    <div class = "artist_images">
                      <%= link_to  image_tag(artist.artist_art, class: 'show_image'), artist_path(artist) %><br/><br/>
                    </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
      <% end %>

      <% #prints message showing that the search does not match %>
      <% if !@artists.present? %>
        <h3><center style = "color: white">There are no artists containing the term(s) "<%= params[:search] %>". Please try 'Adele', 'Drake', 'Kanye West', or 'Taylor Swift'</center></h3>
      <% end %>
```

The controller has the following methods:

```
  def index
    @artists = Artist.all
  end

  def randomPop
    @artists = Artist.where(:genre => "\nPop").random(9)
  end
```

Does anyone know how I can go about changing the variable `@artists` from All artists to those in pop only through a button click?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but you will have to use another server like Faye to request the data dynamically with a WebSocket, just like you'd do in an asynchronous application (like a chat app). Or use AJAX.

Comment: Do you want the whole page to refresh or do it in an AJAXy way?

Comment: @Petr Gazarov, the page is quite small so an entire refresh would be fine

Comment: You can just send a GET request to `randomPop` action. You should post your `routes.rb` - noone is going to guess that for you! :)

Comment: @PetrGazarov my `route.rb` file just has `get 'discovers/index'`, sorry I am very new to RoR so apologies if I come off saying really dumb things.

Comment: I feel it really boils down to just updating the ruby loop within the html, once I can figure that out, everything else should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your view,

```
<%= button_to "Pop", artists_path, method: :get, params: { artist_genre: "Pop" } %>
```

in your controller,

```
def index
  if params[:artist_genre]
    @artists = Artist.where(:genre => params[:artist_genre]).random(9)
  else
    @artists = Artist.all
  end
end
```

Comment: I feel this is probably the answer but I am still not getting anything back

Comment: Never mind, found the issue, it was an odd parsing of the string. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This classic [railscast episode is on point](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form). I would use that for how you set up your search box. The only thing you might alter/update:

```
if search
  find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
else
  find(:all)
end
```

Should probably be a `where` clause based on your situation"

```
if search
  where("genre = ?", your_genre)
else
  all
end
```